# Eclipse rebinding delete line to ctrl+shift+d does not work

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to have eclipse (Luna and Kepler on Ubuntu 12.04) duplicate a line using ctrl+d (like other editors do) and delete it using ctrl+shift+d.

I tried rebinding delete line to ctrl+shift+d, but even if I leave everything else at their default assignments, it simply does not work.

Rebinding line duplication to ctrl+shift+d works perfectly though.

Can anybody tell me please why line deletion is not properly bound to ctrl+shift+d while line duplication could be (there are no binding conflicts in either case)?

Also, is there a way to make delete line work with ctrl+shift+d?

Comment: Can not reproduce, using Debian 6 and Eclipse Helios (guess I should upgrade some time...). Did you remove the binding for Ctrl+D before trying to bind it to the other function?

Comment: I used eclipse Luna and Kepler, both with the same effect. I did remove the bindings (and applied the changes) to both line duplication and deletion before trying to assign ctrl+shift+d to delete line. It still does not work.

Comment: Now on Luna, still works fine. Have you tried using a fresh workspace, just to narrow down the problem? Or maybe it's a conflict with Ubuntu's own key bindings... maybe check out the keyboard configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. Initially, Ctrl+D did not work at all. Then I changed the shortcut to Ctrl+Shift+D, which only worked after I restart eclipse.

Comment: What I found is that you have to pay attention to the When column. Make sure that the text actions happen in the right editor environments. That might increase the chance of cooperation.

Comment: Interestingly I had to change it to Ctrl+Shift+D, then copy that and make it Ctrl-D. After that both of those work, otherwise I could not get Ctrl-D to work in SimRel Ubuntu.

Comment: In Eclipse 2018-12 I also had to define Ctrl-D as "When editing Java source" instead of "When editing text".

Answer (score 0):

(For GTK users (for instance on Ubunutu)): I wanted to bind sort members to Ctrl+Shift+D, but it wasn't working as GTK Debugger was launched on Ctrl+Shift+D. I was able to disable the GTK Debugger key by this key in terminal:

gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding false